# Move in the "string array" with "Next" and "Previous" buttons Java

Tags: java, arrays, button, events, scroll

I would like to scroll through an array with the back and forth buttons. I couldn't find anything online about it, or a few things that didn't help me. I would like a method to be called at my convenience in the button events. My code doesn't work because it immediately shows the last element of the array and not the one following the one present before. Should I try with the `HashMap`  or `ListIterator` or another class? I already tried ListIterator Class, but it works bad.

```
avanti.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            String p1 = "SELECT * FROM Cherubini WHERE lemma LIKE '", p2 = "%';", 
                            px = Lemma.getText(), query = p1+px+p2;
                            int n = main.IdCorrente("SELECT ID FROM Cherubini WHERE definizione = ?", definizione.getText());
                            String[] output = new String[2000000];

                            try {
                                Statement pstmt = null; ResultSet rs = null;
                                pstmt = main.conn().createStatement(); // 
                                rs = pstmt.executeQuery(query);
                               while(rs.next()) { output[0] = rs.getString("lemma");
                                System.out.println(output[0]);
                               output[1] = rs.getString("definizione");
                               System.out.println(output[1]);
                               }
                        } catch(SQLException exc) {}
                
                            lemma.setText(output[0]);
                               definizione.setText(output[1]);
                               output = null;
                        }
                    });
```

My events are two one into other:

```
            Lemma.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)  {
                String p1 = "SELECT * FROM Cherubini WHERE lemma LIKE '", p2 = "%';", 
                        px = Lemma.getText(), query = p1+px+p2;
                        ListIterator<String> itr = null;
                        try {
                            PreparedStatement pst = main.conn().prepareStatement(query);
                            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                String[] out = {rs.getString("lemma"), rs.getString("definizione")};
                                results.add(out);
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {}
                         // here I want set next event and prev event
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> `String p1 = "SELECT * FROM Cherubini WHERE lemma LIKE '", p2 = "%';",`

This in extremely insecure, and will get your computer p0wned by an enterprising russian or whatnot. You cannot do this. You MUST use `PreparedStatement`, and pass in user data using `ps.setString(1, p2)`. If you don't believe me, try entering `Joe'; TRUNCATE Cerubini; --` for funsies.

I'm going to strawman this argument right away because I hear it so often: "But only trusted people enter text in this thing" – Ah, but you see, accidents can happen, and people can be socially engineered to enter dangerous things in text fields because your average user may not know SQL or what fishing attempts look like), or "I'm just learning" – Okay, so why are you learning something that is going to get you fired and possibly sued?

> `while(rs.next()) { output[0] = rs.getString("lemma");`

This code will loop through every row that your select statement finds, and overwrites the first slot in your `output` array. This code is clearly the problem. Fix it to do what you want.

> `} catch(SQLException exc) {}`

Don't do this. Surely I don't to explain why this is a really bad idea. If you don't know how to handle exceptions, the default "I dunno" code is `throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);`, so at the very least, put that in your `{}` instead.

> The general problem

Your code isn't particularly clear, but I guess you want to show the first result from the database, then wait for the user to press some buttons to show the rest.

You have two major ways to do it, and you need to choose which one is appropriate:

### Option 1 - query it all, cache it.

In this option, you query ALL the data, and store it all (you can't just keep overwriting `output`, put it in a list or whatnot, and then have buttons that modify an index variable up or down and updates the graphics with that entry. Something like:

```
// fields
private int index;
private List<String[]> results = new ArrayList<>();

...

while (rs.next()) {
    String[] out = {rs.getString("lemma"), rs.getString("definizione")};
    results.add(out);
}

...

// in the handler for the next button

index++;
nextButton.setDisabled(true);
lemma.setText(results.get(index)[0]);
definizione.setText(results.get(index)[1]);

...
```

### Option 2 - keep querying

The problem with option 1 is, if there are a million records in the DB, you need a ton of RAM to store all those results, also, loading them all might take a good long while. Instead, you can also keep querying the DB every time the next button is pressed.

First of all, the only way to do this right is to ensure the database returns the same result consistently, **which means you need an `ORDER BY` clause on that thing**.

Then on pressing next, you need to spin off a separate thread or spring worker to do the query, then you need to update your UI to show 'in progress' (disable all buttons, show a spinner graphic or whatnot). You can't avoid it for option #1 either, as you should be doing that during the initial query.

This separate thread uses e.g. `OFFSET ? LIMIT 1` and `.setInt(2, idx)` to fetch the right row, and will then use e.g. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to run `lemma.setText` from within there with the result once it is in - and that same invokeLater code should remove all the UI updates to show that data is being loaded (remove the spinner and re-enable the UI elements or whatnot).

Comment: I don't understand you spoke about throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);, where this code goes? - in my code there's already in main throws SQLException

Comment: Yuo're catching SQLException, and the code block that then runs when you capture this exception is: Do nothing and continue silently. Your code, upon an error occurring, will __silently swallow that, throw the error in the trashcan, and continue__ and that is very bad. Put this code in between the `{` and `}` after `catch (SQLException e) {}` in your snippet.

Comment: Could you make a example of Option 2 please?

Comment: @Krisha that's a little too much code, and my swing is too rusty, for a comment, or an answer update.